# YouTube の robots.txt に従ってプログラムからアクセスしても問題ありませんか？

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, youtube

YouTubeにPythonのrequestsを使って定期的にアクセスするBOTを作成中です

YouTubeの規約にはこのような記載があります

Terms of Service : https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=en&gl=US

> You are not allowed to:
>   ~中略~
>   3. access the Service using any automated means (such as robots, botnets or scrapers) except (a) in the case of public search engines, in accordance with YouTube’s robots.txt file; or (b) with YouTube’s prior written permission;

[YouTubeのrobots.txt](https://youtube.com/robots.txt) 内にある `Disallow:` で記述されてないリンクにアクセスします
この場合は規約に遵守しているといえるでしょうか？

### 追記

背景：

- YouTubeのAPIは厳しい使用制限がかかっておりアプリケーションを非常に作りにくい。
- 現在作っているのが開発者側のサーバーを用意せず、クライアント側でYouTubeと通信するアプリケーションを作成しているためAPIを使用した実装はほぼ不可能。

Comment: 敢えて API は使わずに直接クロールするという事でしょうか？

Comment: そういうことです。YOUTUBEのAPIは厳しい使用制限がかかっておりアプリケーションを非常に作りにくいんです

Comment: cubickさん、質問をきれいに手直ししていただきありがとうございます！

Comment: まず、具体的に何をしようとしているのかを明言すべきかと思います。内容によってはあなたが見落としているだけで正規のAPIでも「こんな方法があります」と回答が付くかもしれません。 / 今の「robots.txtに従ってアクセスします」だけだと、最終的な判断をするのはGoogleです、としか回答できません。 / また、APIでの **制限を回避する** 目的でクロール等を行っていると、将来的に新たな制限を設けられる可能性があることを考慮してください。

Comment: そうかもしれませんね。制限を設けられた時の対策は十分に考えておかないといけないとおもいます。

Answer (score 2):

前提として、私は法律の専門家ではないので厳密なところは専門家に聞かないと分からないですが、規約を文字通りに受け取ると、

> access the Service using any automated means **except in the case of public search engines**, in accordance with YouTube’s robots.txt file

太字にした部分に書かれているように、YouTube の事前の許可なくクローリングが可能なのは誰でも使える検索エンジンに限定されています。つまり用途次第ではないでしょうか。

※後からこの Q&A を見に来られた方へ：規約の内容は変わりうるので、必ず最新の利用規約をご確認ください。

API の制限が厳しいのでクロールしたいとのことですが、制限がかかっているのには何かしら理由があるはずなので、これを意図的に回避するのはサービス公開側に親切でなさそうです。YouTube API のクォータを増やす申請をすることを検討してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。誰でも使える検索エンジンの要件を満たすアプリケーションを作ることは可能でしょうか？何が必要でどのような条件であればだれでも使える検索エンジンになりえますか？

Comment: それは私には分かりません。YouTube のサポートに問い合わせてみてください。ただ一般常識として、文字通りの意味なのではないかと推測します。回答にも少し書きましたが、規約の隙間を縫うよりも、クォータを増やしたり、使うクォータを減らす工夫をまずするのを個人的にはオススメしたいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます

Comment: 現在作っているのがクライアント側でスタンドアローンで動かせるアプリケーションを作成しているためapiを使用した実装はほぼ不可能となっております
それがこのような質問をさせていただいた経緯となります

Comment: YouTube のデータを取りに行っていこうとされているのにスタンドアローンというのがよくわかりませんでした。また、クォータ制限はクライアントアプリだろうがウェブアプリだろうか同じような問題になりそうですが違いますか……？

Comment: スタンドアローンという言葉がいけなかったかもしれません。アプリケーション開発の上でサーバーを準備して情報を送らなくてもクライアント側で処理が簡潔するアプリケーションということです。

Comment: スタンドアローンという用語を使ったのが間違えでした。サーバーとの通信を行わないでもひとりでに動き続けるアプリケーションという意味でした（開発者側はサーバーメンテナンスの必要がなくなる）
またウェブアプリであればサーバー管理者が複数のgoogleアカウントを準備すればクオーターはいくらでも確保できます。この作業をアプリを使う一般ユーザーに強いるのはあまりしたくありません。

Comment: ちゃんと規約を読みにいっていませんが、複数アカウント（プロジェクト？）を作ってクォータ制限を回避するのは規約違反っぽい香りがします。それが許されるならクォータ制限は要らないので……。参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239982/youtube-api-quota-multiple-accounts#comment107701159_43214052

Comment: プロジェクトはまた違います。プロジェクトは一つのアカウントで複数個持てるのですが使用できるクオーター最大量を共有してます

Comment: なのでこの参考リンクの回答主はちゃんと質問に答え切ってるか少し疑わしいです

Comment: プロジェクトごとにもクォータ制限があったはずです。ちょっと今手元で確認できないのでドキュメントからの引用になりますが、 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started に "Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation" と書かれています。また、プロジェクトごとの上限だろうがアカウントごとの上限だろうが同じロジックで話ができそうです。リンク先をコメントにしているのはそういう意図です。

Comment: そうなのですね。プロジェクトの一つがクオーター制限がかかったらすべてのプロジェクトで使えなくなって他のアカウントを取り直して作業を続行した記憶（あいまい）があったので勘違いしてしまったかもしれません。